# sed character classes, [:alpha:] appears to match a digit

Tags: regex, sed, centos

Platform is Centos 7

I'm working towards extracting the non-version portion of a filename and puzzled by this result:

```
echo "xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-21.el7.x86_64.rpm" | sed -nr "s/([[:alpha:]]+)-[0-9].*\.*rpm/\1/p"
```

which yields

```
xorg-x11-font-utils
```

hence **[:alpha:]+** appears to match a string including two *1*s, two non-alpha characters. I was expecting this not to match at all.

Explanations?

Comment: Got to say Walter, I think you closed the question prematurely. Effectively "go read the manual" is far from useful. I've given a explanation of what I expect and what I see and could really use a pointer as to how my understanding is flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`([[:alpha:]]+)-[0-9]` matches `utils-7` in your string. When you replace with `\1`, it becomes `utils`.

Everything before (i.e. `xorg-x11-font-`) remains unchanged.

**How it works:**

`\1` is a backreference to group 1, it contains what is match in group 1, in this case `utils`, `-[0-9]` matches `-7` that is just after `utils`, then, `.*\.*rpm`  matches the rest of the string.

The substitution replaces the whole match `utils-7.5-21.el7.x86_64.rpm` with the content of group 1 `utils` so at the end you got :

- the beginning of the string `xorg-x11-font-`, unchanged
- the rest of the string that is replaced with `utils`
- Finally: `xorg-x11-font-utils`

You'll find explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4rFt/1)

Comment: having accepted the answer, for which I'm grateful, I'm now not sure I believe it :-) The replace with \1 should only print the matching group, the bit inside the () - evidence for that: the whole tail is *not* printed. The xorg-x111-font is surely not part of the matching group?

Comment: @djna: See my edit.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I just figured it out myself. Apologies for doubting you, and thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @djna: You're welcome, glad it helps.